# How to make UserControl to use master page placeholders?

Tags: master-pages, user-controls, placeholder

There's quite weird issue and I wonder if it had ever occurred before. 
It looks odd that nobody had been caught by it, by Google says so.

that's what we have:

Master page

Masterpage.master

blahblagblag

User control whose page is bound to mentioned-above master page

According design, we need to define  from .ascx user control

```
SomeControl.ascx

 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="phMaster">  // this will not work, and issue is to make it work
```

But how to do it, considering that user controls cannot be bound to masterpage?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a UserControl can work in the way you are trying to reference it. You would have to put an intermediary aspx page with the master page set which has a Content control referencing your ContentPlaceholder and includes your user control. You can't directly reference that control by going to SomeControl.ascx you'd have to go to a page in which the control sits.